# vue-test-utils 3 setValue() not working on v-select from Vuetifyjs 3

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, vue-test-utils, vitest, vuetifyjs3

I am currently trying to write a test using vitest/vue-test-utils for an app which uses vuetifyjs 3.

My issue currently is I am unable to set values through the v-select and v-autocomplete component (the second one inherits from v-select I believe). On the other hand v-text-field and v-combobox work fine.

I tried to see if I could hook up somewhere in the DOM within the component itself but to no avail. I also tried to access the v-menu component within but here I couldn't access that sub component in the first place. Adding await nextTick() didn't help either.

In a live environment the components work just fine, I can click and choose the values and using vue plugin I see that the v-model gets updated.

Here is the example component code that reproduces my issue:

```
<template>
    <v-select
        variant="outlined"
        class="bar"
        label="context"
        :items="items"
        v-model="context"
        density="compact"
    />
    <v-autocomplete
        variant="outlined"
        class="bat"
        label="context"
        :items="items"
        v-model="context"
        density="compact"
    />
    <v-combobox
        variant="outlined"
        class="baz"
        label="context"
        :items="items"
        v-model="context"
        density="compact"
    />
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
    const items = [
        { title: "a", value: "A" },
        { title: "b", value: "B" },
        { title: "c", value: "C" },
    ];
    var context: string = "D";
</script>
```

and here is the an example test:

```
import { describe, test, expect, afterEach, beforeEach } from "vitest";
import { VueWrapper, mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Context from "~~/components/context.vue";
describe("context", () => {
    let wrapper: VueWrapper;
    let state: { context: string };

    beforeEach(async () => {
        wrapper = mount(Context);
        state = wrapper.vm as unknown as { context: string };
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        wrapper.unmount();
    });

    test("check if context is correctly set", async () => {
        await wrapper.findComponent(".bar").setValue("A");

        expect(state.context).toBe("A");
    });

    test("check if context is correctly set", async () => {
        await wrapper.findComponent(".bat").setValue("B");

        expect(state.context).toBe("B");
    });

    test("check if context is correctly set", async () => {
        await wrapper.findComponent(".baz").setValue("C");

        expect(state.context).toBe("C");
    });
});
```

[vitest screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZgbK.png)

Also even though I am using nuxt, vitest does not use SSR, all the components are tested with client side rendering.

here is the vitest.config.ts:

```
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import { alias } from "./aliases";
import vuetify from "vite-plugin-vuetify";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import AutoImport from "unplugin-auto-import/vite";
import Components from "unplugin-vue-components/vite";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        vuetify({
            autoImport: true,
        }),
        AutoImport({
            imports: ["vue", "vitest"],
            dirs: ["utils"],
        }),
        Components({
            dirs: ["components"],
        }),
    ],
    test: {
        setupFiles: ["css.test.config.js", "plugins.test.config.ts"],
        environment: "happy-dom",
        deps: {
            inline: ["vuetify", "echarts", "vue-echarts"],
        },
        globals: true,
        coverage: {
            provider: "istanbul",
        },
    },
    resolve: {
        alias,
    },
});
```

css.test.config.js:
`global.CSS = { supports: () => false };`

plugins.test.config.ts:

```
import { config } from "@vue/test-utils";
import vuetifyConfig from "~~/vuetify.config";

config.global.plugins = [vuetifyConfig];
```

vuetify.config.ts

```
import { ThemeDefinition, createVuetify } from "vuetify/lib/framework.mjs";
import * as components from "vuetify/components";
import * as directives from "vuetify/directives";
import * as labs from "vuetify/labs/components";


const vuetifyConfig = createVuetify({
    components: {
        ...labs,
        ...components
    },
    directives,
});

export default vuetifyConfig;
```

My hope is to be able to set the value through the component either directly or through hooking into an element within.

Answer (score 1):

Faced a similar problem and there is no normal solution like setValue(). There are two options: use value and set the initial value, or use the select(item: ListItem) method of the VSelect component itself.

Below is a working example, it looks like there is no other solution yet:

```
const component = await wrapper.findComponent(".bar")

component.vm.select({ value: 'a', title: 'A' })
```

VSelect sources see here: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VSelect/VSelect.tsx

Answer (score -1):

I have similar issue using setValue on $refs in Vuetify 3

MyComponent:

```
<template>
<v-combobox v-model=elements />
</template>
<script>
...
    methods:{
     setValue(val) {
          this.elements= val
        }
    }
</script>
```

Parent Component

```
<template>
<MyComponent ref="childComponent" />
</template>
<script>
...
methods:{
 clear(){
this.$refs.childComponent.setValue([])
}
}
</scipt>
```